# Regular expression for extracting no. of days, months and years left

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, regex-group

I'm trying to write a regular expression that extracts the number of time left for something, which can be days, months or years.

For eg, there is a sentence- "This product has a shell life of 21 days or 21 (twenty-one) days or twenty-one days or 21 months, 21 years or five days or 5 (five) days or five (5) days or five(5) days."

I know this is a funny sentence but the point is I want to extract the durations which is in the above sentence.

I have written a regular expression `(?:\w*\-?\w*\s*\(\s*\d+\s*\w*\)\s*\w*|\b\d*\s+\w*\d*)\s*(?:year|month|day)s?` but its not extracting 5 (five) days or the duration which have a digit followed by (words). Can anyone help with the regex ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I came up with `"((?:\d+(?:\s\([a-z-]+\))?|[a-z-]+(?:\s?\(\d+\))?)\s(?:year|month|day)s)"
which does match your sample data.  You're going to get a lot of false positives.  For example, "good days, good years", "one of our better months".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to match the parts in the example data, you might use

```
\w+(?:-\w+)?\s*(?:\(\w+(?:-\w+)?\)\s+)?(?:year|month|days)s?\b
```

The pattern matches:

- `\w+(?:-\w+)?` Match 1+ word char with an optional - and word chars
- `\s*` Match optional whitespace chars
- `(?:\(\w+(?:-\w+)?\)\s+)?` Optionally match from `(` till `)` where there can be word chars with an optional `-` and word chars in between
- `(?:year|month|days)s?` Match any of the alternatives and an optional `s`
- `\b` A word boundary to prevent a partial match

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mT08KL/1) or a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/xhhqAF)

Example

```
import re
from pprint import pprint

regex = r"\w+(?:-\w+)?\s*(?:\(\w+(?:-\w+)?\)\s+)?(?:year|month|days)s?\b"

s = "This product has a shell life of 21 days or 21 (twenty-one) days or twenty-one days or 21 months, 21 years or five days or 5 (five) days or five (5) days or five(5) days."

pprint (re.findall(regex, s))
```

Output

```
['21 days',
 '21 (twenty-one) days',
 'twenty-one days',
 '21 months',
 '21 years',
 'five days',
 '5 (five) days',
 'five (5) days',
 'five(5) days']
```

**Note** that `\s` could possible also match a newline, and `\w` can match digits and chars a-z so there can be a broad range of matches.

Comment: Thankyou so much @the forth bird. You literally saved me.

Comment: And if I want to also match ten ( 10 ) days, what would be the modification in the regex ? @the forth bird

Comment: @UjjwalMahajan Like this? https://regex101.com/r/NrtGwY/1

Comment: You are literally a saviour man ... thankyou @the forth bird

Comment: I also want to match 'one ( 1 ) additional year' in 'up to one ( 1 ) additional year
'

Comment: you can change your name from The fourth bird to 'God of Regex'. Thanks a ton man

Comment: @UjjwalMahajan You are welcome :-) I am just a mere regex fan, there are other users who are the real guru's.

Comment: Just a little issue @The fourth bird, of 21 days is matching instead of 21 days

Comment: You could either optionally match `additional ` like https://regex101.com/r/NJqhL5/1 Should all single words be possible?